# Hibernate: Unable to load class declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry

Tags: java, hibernate

I am completely new in Hibernate and got such an stacktrace:

```
hql> from TracksEntity 
[2014-04-26 21:13:45] org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ model.TracksEntity] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
[2014-04-26 21:13:45] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.TracksEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2188)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2139)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2072)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2045)
    at com.intellij.hibernate.remote.impl.RemoteConfigurationImpl.configure(RemoteConfigurationImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml and TracksEntity.java was automatically generated by Intellij Idea:

TracksEntity.java:
    package model;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRACKS", schema = "APP", catalog = "")
public class TracksEntity {
    private int id;
    private String artist;
    private int duration;
    private String title;
    private String url;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int getId () {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ARTIST")
    public String getArtist () {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist (String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DURATION")
    public int getDuration () {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration (int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    public String getTitle () {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "URL")
    public String getUrl () {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl (String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TracksEntity that = (TracksEntity) o;

        if (duration != that.duration) return false;
        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (artist != null ? !artist.equals(that.artist) : that.artist != null) return false;
        if (title != null ? !title.equals(that.title) : that.title != null) return false;
        if (url != null ? !url.equals(that.url) : that.url != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (artist != null ? artist.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + duration;
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (url != null ? url.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby:/home/zimy/Documents/drbdb;create=true;create=true</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
        <mapping class="model.TracksEntity"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What the problem is? I see that it is not found, but why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds quite silly but i was putting my entity Class in a package which is not the same i put in the mapping.. and hibernate of course could not find it... just for reference.. maybe a recheck can solve your problem best regards.

Answer (score 3):

```
write in this pattern

 <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dairy
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- MAPPING -->
    <!-- <mapping class="com.om.model.Test" /> -->
    <mapping class="com.om.model.RateCalculationBean" />

</session-factory>
```

and also no need to mention scema

Comment: Thank you!  adding <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> to hibernate.cfg.xml make it works. But what that means? Why I got java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.TracksEntity when I had no such property configured?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when the mapping file wouldn´t load correctly. The answer to this problem seems to be that we need to use the correct import statements in our Model classes.

Changing the import to `import javax.persistence.Entity` instead of using the one from hibernate package ( ie `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`), fixed the issue in my case.

This issue is a real pain , and I spent more than 1/2 day looking at all corners, when a simple import fixed the issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by two methods, 2nd one definitely works.

1. Either adding a mapping entry in hibernate.cfg.xml should make it work

> `<mapping class="com.sample.yourClass" />`

2. In your code, After you create Configuration object, Do add class like,

> ```
> Configuration config = new Configuration();
> config.addClass(com.sample.yourClass);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Worked for me**:

Changing position of mapping tag in hibernate.cfg.xml for class which was not loading previously.

I kept that at top now.

Answer (score 0):

i recently experienced this. I checked everything and didn't find anything that might have caused it. In desperation, i just moved the "/>" closer in the mapping and saved it. And it worked. Mysterious...

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was a camel case problem. I had an embedded entity "IndexPK" and wrote "IndexPk" in the mapping file. I compared it ~20 times.... till I figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have just redeployed project. Then problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue add maven spring-boot dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
```

Comment: How do you know they have a Spring setup?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue,
After adding this dependency it's resolved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```