# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="xxxxx"/> in the configuration:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my spring web application I am getting this error on launching my spring application

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryUser"/> in the configuration:
```

Also I have this as a second error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryUser"/> in the configuration:
```

The class DiaryUser is defined in the package and have the following properties assuming the getters and setters are well defined

this is the complete code of my entity class for DiaryUser class.java

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class DiaryUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_USER")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "LOGIN", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public DiaryUser() {
    }
    public DiaryUser(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public DiaryUser(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public DiaryUser(Integer id, String login, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

I have equally defined this in my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryUser" />
        <mapping class="reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryCategory" />
        <mapping class="reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryRecord" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is my data.xml file that contains my database definition configuration for hibernate mappings

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I am kind of confused as I dont know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Could you post full stacktrace and the whole code of your entity class?

Comment: Have shown the complete code of entity class

Comment: can you share data.xml file

Comment: Please try advices described in the following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314412/hibernate-unable-to-load-class-declared-in-hibernate-configuration-mapping-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using LocalSessionFactoryBean,try using the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean instead and specify the mapping classes as shown below(check the link:[AnnotationSessionFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html))

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <property name="annotatedClasses">
     <list>
       <value>test.package.Foo</value>
       <value>test.package.Bar</value>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

or

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.package"/>
 </bean>
```

instead of defining the mappings under hibernate.cfg.xml.

Your sessionFactory details in data.xml file can be modified as below:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!--<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>-->
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
         <list>
           <value>reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryUser</value>
           <value>reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryCategory</value>
           <value>reshetyk.alexey.diary.domain.DiaryRecord</value>
         </list>
       </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: where do I make this modification is it on data.xml file?

Comment: yes,in data.xml where you have defined "sessionFactory"

Comment: Using this approach could you modify my data.xml with your answer to make it more readable and post it as an asnwer.

Comment: Do I overwrite the above with what I have in sessionFactory?

Comment: had missed to update org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean in your sessionFactory definition,please check now

Comment: I have been having series of spring challenges please can you be assisting me?

Comment: Barely new in spring

Comment: Please where did you use this property>>>>>>> <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

Comment: And what does it mean?

Comment: sure,if its something I am aware of,will be glad to help...we can post our queries, and any one of us who might have got similar issues earlier,would help.. :)

Comment: Please where did you call this property>>>>>>> <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> and what does it do

Comment: its the same as what you have done in your data.xml file,we need to give the details of our database,the things which you would give for normally connecting to a database:driver,url,username,password. and hibernate would use these datasource details to connect to DB.

Comment: Is this like a constant to the spring container <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

Comment: Like something like this <property name="datasource" ref="datasource" /> would throw error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114529/discussion-between-s-b-and-blaze).

Comment: Yes it would throw an error if you use "datasource" instead of "dataSource". If you check the class file for "AbstractSessionFactoryBean" class it will have a field: "private DataSource dataSource;" and this is what we are setting using the "dataSource" bean id.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that mapping resource is correctly defined.

Comment: which mapping resource do you mean.

Comment: <mapping resource="domain-classes.hbm.xml"/>