# hibernate models are within a dependancy , how to i access from hbm file?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-annotations

I have a project with a models package, containing model classes using hibernate annotations. I have another project which has the functionality using these models, which is where the .hbm file is located. within the .hbm file is the following

```
<"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/logging</property>
 <property name="connection.username">root</property>
 <property name="connection.password">my-secret-pw</property>
 <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <mapping class="com.filament.models.Customer"/>
 <mapping class="com.filament.models.BackgroundService"/>

</session-factory>
```

The mapping class tag is clearly not pointing to the correct place , that is the package, but in the containing dependancy. (the project is in a maven repo and imported as a dependency in the pom (its perfectly accessible from java code level using an import). How do i point to the models within the dependency ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, can you post that as well?

Comment: yes the error is that it can not find the mapping class. (as would be expected).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `mapping jar`, i.e

```
<mapping jar="myJarfile.jar"/>
```

Comment: This sounds promising, i would i using this from a maven dependancy ?

Comment: @robm it should be able to retrieve from a maven dep I believe.

Comment: ok nice wil give it ok. but how then do i point it towards the package within that jar?

Comment: @robm you will still have the `mapping class` tags with the fully qualified class names

Comment: I have tried using that towards the .jar file behind the dependancy but then errors saying it doesnt know what it is

Answer (score 0):

Put your entity class in a package. Then put it in the mapping. I think you have some problem in

```
 <mapping class="com.filament.models.Customer"/>
 <mapping class="com.filament.models.BackgroundService"/>
```

**Package name:** `com.filament.models`

**Class name** should be:

1. Customer.java
2. BackgroundService.java

Check that is there any missing some classes.

### Resource Link:

[Hibernate: Unable to load class declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314412/hibernate-unable-to-load-class-declared-in-hibernate-configuration-mapping-e)